# Texturing down plane (WebGL, Three.JS)

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am using three.js. with webGL. I have a single texture file called support.jpg 100x100.

I am creating planes on the fly, with different heights and widths. I need the support.jpg texture to scale to the width and then repeat down the plane. (as soon in image below)

For Example. If the plane was (height:10, width: 10) it would the texture once fiting. If the plane was (height:100, width: 10) it would have 10 of the textures repeating 10by10. If the plane was (height:100, width: 50) it would have 2 of the textures repeating 50by50.

**Question**: How Do I Create a plane that will have the correct texture mapping.

Here is what I have so far, but it is only rendering a single texture. (this is a width 200, height 800)

```
       function CreateSupportBeam() {

        var mesh, texture, material;

        texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/support.png");
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, transparent: true });

        var uvs = [];
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(0,0));
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(1,0));
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(1,4));
        uvs.push(new THREE.Vector2(0,4));

        var geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 800);
        geo.faceVertexUvs[0].push([uvs[0], uvs[1], uvs[2], uvs[3]]);

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);

        scene.add(mesh);
    }
```

[rollercoaster.dickinsonbros.com/](http://rollercoaster.dickinsonbros.com/) <- This is the project I am working on.
[image]

Comment: Updated the First post to make more clear. But the question is how do i get a texture to repeat on a plane, but scale to the width of that plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to change the UVs.

Use a pattern like the following to avoid distortion and ensure that the pattern repeats and starts at the "top".

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( length, height );

var scale = height / length;
var offset = Math.floor( scale ) - scale;;

var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( ... );

texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

texture.repeat.set( 1, scale );
texture.offset.set( 0, offset );
```

If that is not exactly what you are looking for, experiment until you get it the way you want it.

three.js r.66

Comment: Yes This is what i was looking for. Thanks been working on this for quite a while trying another path to get the result. Thanks! you Da Man.